# How to stack columns to rows in Python?

Tags: python, stack, transpose

For example, the data structrue is like below.

```
import pandas as pd

source={
'Genotype1':["CV1","CV1","CV1","CV1","CV1"], 
'Grain_weight1':[25,26,30,31,29], 
'Genotype2':["CV2","CV2", "CV2","CV2","CV2"],
'Grain_weight2':[29,32,33,32,30]
}

df=pd.DataFrame(source, index=[1,2,3,4,5])
df
```

[image]

and now I'd like to transpose two columns to rows like below. Could you let me know how to do that?

[image]

Thanks,

Comment: There's a difference between `df.T` transpose and [stack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)ing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not transposing. This is actually vertical stacking. You can achieve the same by the following code:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.vstack([df[df.columns[2:].to_list()].to_numpy(),
           df[df.columns[:2].to_list()].to_numpy()]), columns = df.columns[:2])
```

Comment: You don't need the `.to_list()`s. The problem with the solution is that it gives the column `Grain_weight1` an `object` dtype instead of `int64`: look at `print(result["Grain_weight1"].dtype)` or `result.info()`. (It also seems to be significantly slower for large dataframes, like more than 10,000 rows).

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following:

```py
result = pd.concat(
    [df[["Genotype1", "Grain_weight1"]],
     df[["Genotype2", "Grain_weight2"]].rename(lambda c: f"{c[:-1]}1", axis=1)],
    ignore_index=True
)
```

Result for the sample:

```
  Genotype1  Grain_weight1
0       CV1             25
1       CV1             26
2       CV1             30
3       CV1             31
4       CV1             29
5       CV2             29
6       CV2             32
7       CV2             33
8       CV2             32
9       CV2             30
```